# How to change the colour of menu in Tkinter under windows?

Tags: python, tkinter, menubar

I'm using **windows xp**. I want to change menubar and labels foreground and background in TKinter. But, I'm unable to change. Can I change it in windows xp or I have to upgrade it to windows 7.

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

menubar = Menu(root)
menubar.add_command(label = 'Label1', command = log, background = 'Black', foreground = 'Red')

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

I'm able to display what I want and my code is **working perfectly in Linux**. But, it's not changing the color in window. Do I need to use any additional commands to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing you can do. Tkinter uses a native menu object for the menus, which means they will have exactly the same look and feel of other windows menus.

Comment: But, what's the purpose of giving those options for menus? In that case can that menu on canvas using canvas.create_window option?

Comment: Under Linux, it's working perfectly. Means, I can't change them  under windows only, right?

Comment: Is there anyway to add the menu to canvas in Tkinter?

Answer (score 0):

```
from Tkinter import *
def log():
        print 'in log fun'

root = Tk()

menubar = Menu(root)
menubar.add_command(label = 'Label1', command = log)
```

> root.config(bg='red',menu=menubar)

```
root.mainloop()
```

you can config the background color, not possible to menu background color.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmNiS.png)