# Change Tkinter Dropdownmenu backgroundcolor

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, tkinter

we are currently programming a game with python in school. I managed to create a Dropdown Menu with different Submenus. 
I'm now asking myself if there is a way to change the backgroundcolour of the Dropdown Menu.

[As you can see, the background colour is gray at the moment, is there any way to change the colour to a dark-blue?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpN2Y.jpg)

```
try:
    import tkinter
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tkinter

main = tkinter.Tk()

menu = tkinter.Menu(master=main)
main.config(menu=menu)

subMenu = tkinter.Menu(master=menu, tearoff=0, bg="#476581", fg="white", font=("Trebuchet MS", 13))
menu.add_cascade(label="Schiffe", menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label="deine Schiffe")
subMenu.add_separator()
subMenu.add_command(label="Schiffe kaufen")

lagerMenu = tkinter.Menu(master=menu, tearoff=0, bg="#476581", fg="white", font=("Trebuchet MS", 13))
menu.add_cascade(label="Lager", menu=lagerMenu)
lagerMenu.add_command(label="dein Lager")
lagerMenu.add_separator()
lagerMenu.add_command(label="Lager kaufen")

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please write a minimal, complete and verifiable example, your current code wouldn't run as a standalone script

Comment: [Pulldown menus (and other submenus) are created in a similar fashion](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm), so try `menu = tkinter.Menu(master=main, bg="#476581", fg="white", font=("Trebuchet MS", 13))`. [But I think this options are platform specified](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24111995/6634373).